# Function Template Specialization Error

Tags: c++, function, templates, function-templates

I am trying to specialize my function template for list of int pointers.

```
template <typename typ>
void sortowanie(typ *tablica, int rozmiar, Komparator<typ> *komparator)
{
    int p;
    for(int j = rozmiar - 1; j > 0; j--)
    {
        p = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
            if(komparator->porownaj(tablica[i], tablica[i + 1]))
            {
                typ pom = tablica[i];
                tablica[i] = tablica[i + 1];
                tablica[i + 1] = pom;
                p = 0;
            }
        if(p) break;
    }
};

template<>
void sortowanie<int *>(int **tablica, int rozmiar, Komparator<int> *komparator)
{
    int p;
    for(int j = rozmiar - 1; j > 0; j--)
    {
        p = 1;
        for(int i = 0; i < j; i++)
            if(komparator->porownaj(*tablica[i], *tablica[i + 1]))
            {
                int *pom = tablica[i];
                tablica[i] = tablica[i + 1];
                tablica[i + 1] = pom;
                p = 0;
            }
        if(p) break;
    }
};
```

But I get the following errors:

```
obliczenia.cpp:43:10: error: template-id ‘sortowanie<int*>’ for ‘void obliczenia::sortowanie(int**, int, Komparator<int>*)’ does not match any template declaration
void sortowanie<int*>(int* * tablica, int rozmiar, Komparator<int> *komparator) {
              ^
obliczenia.cpp:43:10: error: template-id ‘sortowanie<int*>’ for ‘void obliczenia::sortowanie(int**, int, Komparator<int>*)’ does not match any template declaration
void sortowanie<int*>(int* * tablica, int rozmiar, Komparator<int> *komparator) {
```

Comment: Just overload - do not specialize (omit the `template<>` in the second function)

Comment: if i'm trying use 

void sortowanie(int* * tablica, int rozmiar, Komparator<int> *komparator) 


c++ return


multiple definition of `obliczenia::sortowanie(int**, int, Komparator<int>*)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this is a typo.

In the generic template version, you have:

```
template <typename typ>
void sortowanie(typ *tablica, int rozmiar, Komparator<typ> *komparator) {
```

In the specialization, you have:

```
template<>
void sortowanie<int*>(int* * tablica, int rozmiar, Komparator<int> *komparator) {
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I suspect you mean that to be: `Komparator<int*> *komparator`.

Without that, the function can be an overload but it can't be a template specialization. In that case, you need to remove the `template <>` before the function declaration.

Comment: i fix it but still `code`(multiple definition of `void obliczenia::sortowanie<int*>(int**, int, Komparator<int*>*))

Comment: @PawełSzymański, I can't think of what else can be done. If you can, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it works when i write "inline" after template<> but i don't know why

Comment: @PawełSzymański it works when you write inline because inline functions must be defined in headers. Otherwise, the fully defined template specialization `template<> void sortowanie<int*> (...)` is not really a template and should be defined in a CPP file for a single implementation, avoiding therefore the multiple definition problem